# Android updates availability in different countries

Tags: ota-update

I am Indian and I just moved in to UK. I have seen some good deals on a mobile and I would like to buy it. But I'm worried if I would get software updates for the mobile that purchased when I reach my country back.I tried googling but I couldn't get hold of anything useful. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, software updates depend on different things:

1. the manufacturer (if they actually release any updates)
2. the carrier (unless you get the international version)
3. your internet connection (no internet = no updates)

You get the updates from the country where you bought the device from (unless you flash a different one, check on the CSC: Carrier/Country Specific Code).

Note that you might need to make at least a 5 minute call using a SIM originating from the buying location to unlock usage of international carriers' SIM cards. Also make sure all the needed bands for connecting to the network of your carrier (most phones support all bands, so no real problem there).

All these note are also printed on the package, in the user manual or both.